# I want to add the data of input fields and wanna show them in other input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have three input fields I want to get the sum of two input fields and put the result 3rd input field like this.

```
  <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="subTotal" class="form-label">SubTotal</label>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" required>
     </div>
     </div>
    <div class="row mt-2">
       <div class="col-md-2">
     <label for="discount" class="form-label">Discount</label>
        </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discount" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discountResult">
   </div>
 </div>
```

In this code, I want to add the Subtotal value with discount value and show the result in the discount input text field.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would checkout [mcve] first.

Comment: Can I explain to you?

Comment: SO requires you to research and attempt the code first. Then after at if your code is failing then you post it here for assistance if fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function below using your HTML.

It will take the value of subtotal and subtract the discount value `onchange`.

```js
var subTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal');
var discount = document.getElementById('discount');
var discountResult = document.getElementById('discountResult');

discount.addEventListener("change", function() {
  discountResult.value = subTotal.value - discount.value;
});
```

```html
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="subTotal" class="form-label">SubTotal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="discount" class="form-label">Discount</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discount" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discountResult">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="subTotal" class="form-label">SubTotal</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="subTotal" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="discount" class="form-label">Discount</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discount" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="discountResult">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function sum()
{
var subTotal = document.getElementById("subTotal"); 
var discount = document.getElementById("discount"); 
var result=subTotal+discount;

document.getElementById("discountResult").value = result;
}
```